# IPv4 TCP checksum calculation

Tags: tcp, checksum, ipv4

I'm having issues trying to get the overall checksum to match in a sample IPv4 packet. I was successful in getting the header checksum to match.

Here's the complete frame from Wireshark:

```
2cfd
a1bf
5450 (src addr)
e45f
0123
15b9 (dest addr)
0800 (type = IPv4 protocol)
4500 (version/header length)
0028 (total length)
cef0 (identification)
4000 (flags)
4006 (time to live)
e986 (header checksum)
c0a8
0096 (src IP addr)
c0a8
0072 (dest IP addr)
b26e (src port)
fdb8 (dest port)
42c6
1f88 (seq number)
68dc
6995 (ack number)
5010 (header length/flags)
01f6 (window size)
469e (checksum)
0000 (urgent pointer)
0000
0000
0000 (data/pad)
```

I'm a little confused which bytes get used to compute the checksum.

Here's what I tried and got the closest to matching (starting with src addr):
c0a8+0096+c0a8+0072+b26e+fdb8+42c6+1f88+68dc+6995+5010+01f6+0000(checksum)+0000+0000+0000=4b943

This becomes: b947 (adding the overflow back in) and inverted becomes: 46b8

Wireshark shows 469e as the checksum.

Could someone point out to my error in this calculation?

Thanks.

Comment: The TCP checksum is computed over the "pseudo header" which includes src-addr, dst-addr, protocol and tcp segment length followed by the tcp segment (tcp header+ data).  So I think if you add protocol and the tcp segment length (calculated, not a field in any header) you should be good to go.

Comment: Okay. I get it now.

Comment: Okay. I get it now. So, protocol=6 and tcp segment length = total length - (4*IHL) = 28-(4*5) = 14. Total equation is now 14 + 6 + 18258 + 336eb = 4b95d => b961 => 469e. This matches. Thanks!